# How to merge rectangles which have been rotated

Tags: merge, three.js, rotation

Using three.js,I bumped into a problem. I would appreciate it if someone help me out.
My goal is the following;

1 First step:
    Set two rectangles adjacent to each other with a certain angle.

2 Second step:
    Rotate them together with the same axis and the same rotation angle.

Before merging them, I need to rotate one of the rectangles to do the first step. Then I try to merge them,but the rotated rectangle is not rendered,that
is, it's disappeared.
  I simplified the problem,that is ,
If you rotate a rectangle before merging, the rectangle is gone.
What shall I do?

The snippet of my code(simplified version;I omitted the part of rectangle2) is:

```
1 var rectangle1Geometry=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,10);
2 var rectangle1Material=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
3 var rectangle1=new THREE.Mesh(rectangle1Geometry,rectangle1Material);
4 rectangle1.position.set(0,0,-5);
5 rectangle1.rotation.x=Math.PI./2;
6 rectangle1.updateMatrix();
7 var singleGeometry=new THREE.Geometry();
8 singleGeometry.merge(rectangle1.geometry,rectangle1.matrix);
9 var material=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
10 var mesh=new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry,material);
11 scene.add(mesh);
12 renderer.render(scene,camera);
```

If I exclude line5,I can see the image of rectangle1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors in your console?
You have a typo in your code. But I am not sure if that is causing the problem...

```
rectangle1.rotation.x = Math.PI./2;
```

should be

```
rectangle1.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to draw both sides of the plane. Change the following two lines

```
var rectangle1Material=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
var material=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
```

to -

```
var rectangle1Material=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var material=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide});
```